# The empty path didn’t match any of these. Django

Tags: python, django

I'm a total beginer at Django. Please help me to solve it, I've been trying to do so for 2 days. Essentially I created a model, defined a class there but when I open the page I get the error

```
Using the URLconf defined in reports_proj.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

settigs.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #our apps
    'customers',
    'products',
    'profiles',
    'reports',
    'sales',
    #3rd party
    'crispy_forms'
]
```

When I put  `path('login/', admin.site.urls),` **it works** but shows me `Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account.` whenever I try to log in as admin.

It seems like I should write some methods in *views.py*, because it has only `from django.shortcuts import render` line. If it's true, **which ones?**

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Are you trying to login to the Django admin site? Why are you changing the path from `admin/` to `login/`?

Comment: Yes, to django admin site. I did it just to see if it works other way

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you not able to login?

Comment: In general, I can't open the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain how django works in a simple way.

In urls.py you define which view (from views.py) will be shown, In views.py you  link template(HTML) and pass data from database (models.py) to this HTML

So if you want to create for example car dealership website you would need to

1. In Models.py create a model for a car,
2. In templates/ create a HTML file with a front-end
3. In views.py pass car model from models.py to template (HTML)
4. In urls.py link views.py to a certain path

if users goes to [www.domain.com/cars](http://www.domain.com/cars) django will first look at urls.py to check if you defined "/cars" path -> from there check linked view.py to see which HTML show to a user

I would advise you to go though Django tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/
[image: diagram how django works]

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation, especially for the picture

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you settings.py file apps names I think you were learning django from you tube video Django with pandas and matlpotlib.

I also watched and had the same problem. As mentions above solution, you need to connect base.html file from template to customers/view.py file. Even after connecting to it you need to have some javascript and css files in static folder. Because after you connect base.html file to customer/view.py django asks the js and css files that are specified inside the base.html. So the tutor does not build or provide all the materials in the source link he provided under the video tutorial.

So my final suggestion is if you can build the required js and css code files and put inside static folder. then it works if there is no other problem.
But my prefered way is do not panic or get nervous because of inadequecy of the video tutorials.

Search for other ones.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll get back to that project and try one more time with your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. in your settings.py replace the `STATIC_ROOT` and the `STATICFILES_DIRS` with this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<APPNAME>/static/')
]
```

Replace <APPNAME> with the name of your project.

**This will set the root directory path.**

*The error that you are being displayed above is because you haven't set a urls.py and views.py yet!*